# c++/cx - Error: a delegate type is not allowed here

Tags: lambda, delegates, c++-cx

I need to capture a lambda expression in c++/cx and pass it as a parameter to a `public ref class MyClass sealed` component class. I tried to use a `std::function`, but the compiler complains `signature of public member contains native type 'std::func...`

I have been reading and reading, and `public delegate void MyCallback(byte, byte, byte *)` looks like it is supposed to be a replacement for `typedef std::function<void(byte, byte, byte *)> MyCallback;`

I've tried using it as a parameter:

```
void
attach (
    byte cmd_,
    MyCallback cb_
);
```

However, Intellisense gives me the error: `"Error: a delegate type is not allowed here".`

I don't get it... How are you supposed to pass functions around, and what would it look like?

Comment: You should be able to use the std:: function and pass it into an internal-scoped method (not public) of MyClass. If that doesn't help could you post a larger code sample so that I can reproduce?

Comment: @robwirving c++/cx does not allow `std::function` to be exposed in a method signature of a `public ref class`

Comment: It doesn't allow a method signature to be exposed in with the public access specifier. But there is the internal specifier which allows you to expose publicly to non C++/CX classes. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh969551.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your MyCallback type is a managed delegate than you have to specify that you are accepting a managed reference of that type:

```
void
attach (
    byte cmd_,
    MyCallback^ cb_
);
```

Mind the **`^`** sign. Without this sign you will see a strange error: `a delegate type is not allowed here`. This sign literally means `a managed reference of type ...`.